# Iterative calculation of a number-theoretical constant

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-theory

Recently the decimal expansion of a number theoretic constant 
was searched for, which is the analog of the Landau-Ramanujan 
constant in a certain context. The constant starts 0.638909...

It can be computed as:

```
prec := 200; 
A = N[ 2^(-1/2) 3^(-1/4), prec ];
For[ n = 1, n < 100000, n++, p = Prime[n]; 
    If[ Mod[p, 3] == 2, A = A / Sqrt[(1 - 1/p) (1 + 1/p)] ] 
]
Print[A]
```

I would like to know as many exact digits as possible, or say the first 100 digits.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this and at the same time ensure the validity of the digits?

Comment: `C` is a system variable, so don't use it. Can you give a source for the algorithm you presented? Anyway, you don't really need to use `For[]`: `Product[N[1/Sqrt[(1 - 1/p) (1 + 1/p)], 250], {p, Select[Prime[Range[1*^5]], Mod[#, 3] == 2 &]}]/(Sqrt[2] 3^(1/4))`

Comment: OK, so what's the benefit of that? It's just harder for me to read and understand. And I do not get a statement about the validity of the decimals either.

Comment: For starters, you still haven't answered my question. Any additional background might help answer your question about "validity of the decimals". As for my code, maybe this version is more easier for you to "read and understand": `Product[With[{p = Prime[k]}, If[Mod[p, 3] == 2, N[1/Sqrt[(1 - 1/p) (1 + 1/p)], 250], 1]], {k, 1, 10^5}]/(Sqrt[2] 3^(1/4))`?

Comment: J. M., you are an expert, I know, yet you don't answer my question. 
"How to ensure the validity of the digits?"  Tutoring in Mathematica syntax for the advanced doesn't help in this case and is not in demand.

Comment: @Apostrophos No need to be snippy. I am sure, if J.M. would consider his comment as a complete answer, he would have posted it as such. Really, using `For` is one of the worst things to use if it is about performance (which was also an aspect of your question).

Comment: We neither know how the constant is called nor any paper where this algorithm is discussed. Usually, the one who proposes and advertises an algorithm is in charge to derive error estimates.

Comment: If you truncate at prime `p`, the relative error is `O(1/(p log p))`. So this will need quite a lot of primes to get 100 digits correct.

Comment: Looking at the comments it appears this is a math question, nothing to do with Mathematica. Voting to migrate it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau There is exactly zero/rien/nada mathematics in my question (apart perhaps from deep error analysis, which I am not asking for). But if you succeed after 5 minutes of thinking in telling me how to write this function in Mathematica such that it is guaranteed to return 10 valid decimal places, then I estimate you even higher than I already do.

Comment: The comments led me to believe it was the error analysis that was of interest and not the code per se. As for 10 valid digits, I believe some of the other responses will come close to that if you use 10^7 or so primes.

Comment: `0.6389094054` appears to be correct to 10 places. But...ensuring the validity of the digits really does come down to the error analysis more than the code.

Answer (score 8):

It's a good idea to switch as early as possible to finite precision. Currently, `1/ Sqrt[(1 - 1/p) (1 + 1/p)]` is computed in exact arithmetic (and probably some time is wasted to decide that the `Sqrt` cannot be resolved exactly). As J.M. already pointed out, also `For` is not a performance booster. Better utilize that arithmetic operations such as `Plus`, `Times`, `Mod` etc. are `Listable`. Moreover, the rather expensive operations such as `Sqrt` and `Divide` commute with `Times` so that they may be applied less often. Moreover, using `Subtract[1,x]` and `Divide[1,x]` instead of `1-x` and `1/x` leads to a tiny speedup (this is because, e.g., `y/x` is interpreted by Mathematica as `y * (1/x)` which contains a superfluous multiplication).

```
ClearAll[A];
A[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: 200] := Module[{p, p2},
  p = Prime[Range[n]];
  p2 = N[Pick[p, Mod[p, 3], 2], prec];
  N[2^(-1/2) 3^(-1/4), prec]/ Sqrt[Times @@ Subtract[1, Divide[1, p2^2]]]
  ]

A[100000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.241356, 0.63890939726017130408440290791950881418165845460093007138302026669815
>   1893498896918805566151830415302075625388325192796690975902066185385403
>   03088163214273320600204154041174777934833253718149874713993272}

However, this is *far* away to be correct up to 100 digits: for example, `A[100000] - A[1000000]` is only of order `10^-8`. But that's not my fault; it's the algorithm's.

The (truncated) sequence can be obtained (at a price of some performance loss) with the following function:

```
ClearAll[Alist];
Alist[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: 200] := Module[{p, p2, q},
  p = Prime[Range[n]];
  p2 = N[Pick[p, Mod[p, 3], 2], prec];
  q = Sqrt[Divide[1, Subtract[1, Divide[1, N[p2^2, prec]]]]];
  N[2^(-1/2) 3^(-1/4), prec] FoldList[Times, q]
  ]
```

One might try to apply extrapolation techniques (e.g. `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit ``) to the result (the `Differences` of the truncated sequence seem to have a rather smooth tail), but I am not an expert in this matter. J.M. is. Maybe if you kindly ask him...

Comment: I would use `Prime[Range[n]]` to exploit listability. I was going to try doing an analysis of the decay rate of the terms, but the uncooperativeness of the OP put me off. (+1 anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

An approach using [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html); however, slower than Henrik's solution

```
ClearAll[A2];
A2[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: 200] := Module[{p, p2},
  p = Prime[Range[n]];
  p2 = N[Pick[p, Mod[p, 3], 2], prec];
  Fold[#1/Sqrt[1 - 1/#2^2] &, N[2^(-1/2) 3^(-1/4), prec], p2]]

A2[100000] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.391856, \
0.6389093972601713040844029079195088141816584546009300713830202666981518934988\
969188055661518304153020756253883251927966909759020661853854030308816321427332\
0600204154041174777934833253718149874713993272} *)
```